# Is this an inconsistency in the Infinity War and Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In Infinity War, Thanos explains to Gamora that killing half of her people saved them from inevitable doom.

> You know what's happened since then? The children born have known nothing but full bellies and clear skies. It's a paradise.

Further, we see flashbacks that he indeed kills half of the population. But, in Guardians of the Galaxy, when a profile of Gamora is shown while she enters the prison with Star Lord, it says that she is

> the last survivor of the Zehoberei people

[image: the last survivor of the Zehoberei people]

Was this an oversight in either movie?

Comment: Just because a Xandarian record says something doesn't necessarily mean it's a fact. She may not even weigh 852 grets...

Comment: She is the last Zehoberei, as much as Kal-El is the last of Kryptonians...

Comment: This is almost definitely a mistake. The script for Infinity War wasn't written until after GotG was already out, so James Gunn wouldn't have known that they planned on using Gamora's planet in that way. And in the comics, the Gamora comes from the future, when she _is_ the last living of her species. The writers of Infinity War might not have realized that they contradicted GotG, or (more likely) the Marvel producers decided that a small line of text from GotG could just be ignored. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if someone at Marvel tries to come up with an in-world explanation for this

Comment: Entirely possible that Zehoberei is the name of her tribe/society on her home planet, and that the rest of them were wiped out by Thanos' attack - it's not like the soldiers appeared to be splitting then up in families or groups, just making sure the halves were equal?

Comment: Good answer to this on the SciFi Stack Exchange: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194181/24826 (Spoiler: It may be an error in GotG!)

Comment: Maybe their bellies are full of *lead* (or other toxic substance that leads to a violent euphemism)

Answer (score 4):

The destruction of the Zehoberei people may have come long after Thanos' attack on the planet. Gamora was only a little girl when it happened, and it doesn't appear that Thanos revisited her planet after the genocide.

Edit: Thanos never says *when* he went back to her planet. Estimates put her age at 26 during IW, and she looks to be around 8-10 when Thanos kidnaps her. Even if we knock off a couple of years to account for GotG, an extremely conservative estimate puts the time range at 10 years between kidnap and IW. That's a long time for catastrophes to happen.

I'm not saying Thanos' strategy killed her people. I'm saying that Thanos went back after he halved their population, observed that they were thriving, left, and then a catastrophe befell them that killed the entire population.

Comment: In Infinity War, didn't Thanos state that he went back and that her planet was now prosperous? That's what the first line in the question was alluding to.

Comment: Good question, edited my post to elucidate.

Answer (score 0):

To offer a theory: as a planet conquerer, Thanos could have renamed the surviving half of the Zehoberei people, seeing them as a new race with a new future, leaving his mark of salvation on them.  As Thanos would be a feared and renowned conquerer throughout the universe, the rest of the universe would recognize this change as absolute. Gamora, being loyal to her family and hating Thanos, would still call herself a Zehoberei. Therefore, Gamora would be seen as the last survivor of the people she still claims to be a part of.

Comment: Theories are acceptable as long as there's canon evidence to back them up, so in this case, you'd need to provide evidence that Thanos renamed what was left of her race (or would be inclined to do so).

Answer (score -2):

I don't see how that's an inconsistency. The fact that Thanos believes in, and propagates, a genocidal Malthusian ideology doesn't mean that he's *right*. It would only be an oversight if

1. You accept Thanos' premise that this is the only way to save life in the universe, and
2. You believe his plan is *infallible*, meaning that once he killed half the population of a world, nothing *else* could happen to eradicate that world's population.

I don't accept #1 (which is a silly argument for many reasons), and certainly #2 is obviously false - Thanos doesn't *promise* eternal success for any planet, just removes what is (to his mind) the biggest reason for failure.

His actions might have (to his mind, again) saved the Zenoberi from collapse. They might have died out later on for other reasons.

Comment: Thanos actually does [say this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/quotes/qt3943022) about Gamora's home planet: _"You know what's happened since then? The children born have known nothing but full bellies and clear skies. __It's a paradise__."_

Comment: @Oliver_C He might be lying or misinformed. Really, why should we trust Thanos?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon: Lying seems out of character for Thanos. Yes, he's a genocidal villain and all that, but Thanos himself claims Gamora didn't learn to lie from him (which is why she's bad at it) and the tone he uses implies that being truthful is kind of a big thing for him. More to the point, he has little motivation to actually lie to Gamora about this particular fact; he could have simply mentioned another planet where things worked out better. I'll buy "misinformed", but not "lying".

Comment: @JeroenMostert I personally would accept "So conceited as to assume everything goes according to his expectations without verifying in the slightest". I don't know that that's *entirely* within character for Thanos, but he certainly seems entirely convinced that there's no way his solution could be worse than the alternative.